# CSS background scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css

how do I make the page background scroll horizontally while scrolling the page vertically??

here is a working example to illustrate what I mean.

http://www.hul.co.in/careers-jobs/

Comment: they have used javascript to change the background-position attribute on window.scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do with pure css, you'll have to use javascript.

If you're using jQuery, you can use this:

**Just the basic HTML markup:**

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="content"> <!-- add some content here --> </div>
```

**CSS styling:**

```
/* css */
#background {
    /* fixed position - aways on top of the screen */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    /* set repeat-x so it doesn't run off */
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/3000x100/333/999.png&text=foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar) repeat-x;

    /* you MUST set width and height or it won't display */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;

    /* -1 to ensure it will always be in background */
    z-index: -1;
}

#content{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #b0b0b0;
}
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
// JavaScript (using jQuery)
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // parse the value of current background position and add window.scrollY - vertical scroll (divide this for slower background scroll)
    var offset = parseInt($("#background").css("background-position-x")) + window.scrollY;
    $("#background").css("background-position", offset + "px 0px");
});
```

If you'd like to see this code at work, look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/7snre/2/).

If you would like to avoid using jQuery, I have converted this same code to work in pure js: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/U9FQc/1/).

Answer (score 1):

They are using JavaScript (specifically [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library) for this job in this [script](http://uimg.unilever.com/central/script/custom.js).
I'd recommend using jQuery as it "normalizes" browsers vendor-prefixed properties.

Something like this could get you started,

```
var lastTop = 0,
    top = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    top = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (lastTop !== top) {
        // If it's scrolling vertically
        // change background's x coordinate
        $(this).animate({
            'background-position-x': top;
        }, 1);

        lastTop = top;
    }
});
```